# Fody: An Unhandled Exception Occured

Tags: c#, assemblies, fody-costura

I am suddenly getting an exception when trying to build the project. Seems to have something todo with Mono.Cecil. But I am not using Mono in my project.

> Fehler    13  Fody: An unhandled exception occurred: Exception: Die Datei
>   oder Assembly "Mono.Cecil, Version=0.9.6.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde
>   nicht gefunden. Die gefundene Manifestdefinition der Assembly stimmt
>   nicht mit dem Assemblyverweis überein. (Ausnahme von HRESULT:
>   0x80131040) StackTrace:    bei System.Signature.GetSignature(Void*
>   pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle,
>   IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)    bei
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.FetchNonReturnParameters()    bei
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParametersNoCopy()    bei
>   System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetIndexParametersNoCopy()
>   bei System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters()    bei
>   System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyCandidates(String name, BindingFlags
>   bindingAttr, Type[] types, Boolean allowPrefixLookup)    bei
>   System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyImpl(String name, BindingFlags
>   bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[] types,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers)    bei System.Type.GetProperty(String
>   name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[]
>   types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)    bei
>   PropertyDelegateBuilder.BuildPropertySetDelegate[T](Type type, String
>   propertyName) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\7495521761d392b9\FodyIsolated\DelegateBuilders\PropertyDelegateBuilder.cs:Zeile
>   9.    bei DelegateBuilder.BuildDelegateHolder(Type weaverType) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\7495521761d392b9\FodyIsolated\DelegateBuilders\DelegateBuilder.cs:Zeile
>   25.    bei DelegateBuilder.GetDelegateHolderFromCache(Type weaverType) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\7495521761d392b9\FodyIsolated\DelegateBuilders\DelegateBuilder.cs:Zeile
>   16.    bei InnerWeaver.InitialiseWeavers(List`1 weaverInstances) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\7495521761d392b9\FodyIsolated\InnerWeaver.cs:Zeile
>   65.    bei InnerWeaver.Execute() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\7495521761d392b9\FodyIsolated\InnerWeaver.cs:Zeile
>   30. Source: mscorlib TargetSite: Void GetSignature(Void*, Int32, System.RuntimeFieldHandleInternal, System.IRuntimeMethodInfo,
>   System.RuntimeType)

Any ideas? I already tried to reinstall the Costura.Fody package.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by downgrading from Version 1.3.4 to 1.3.3 by executing

> Install-Package Costura.Fody -Version 1.3.3.0

in Package-Manager-Console.

Answer (score 2):

Try to update Costura.Fody packages for your project. For me it was enough.

Comment: Yepp, we solved this problem by updating our packages in all projects to common version. I guess the main problem was caused by mismatching Fody versions in projects.

Answer (score 1):

Having the exact same issue here.

It used to work last week, we did not change anything and now Costura.Fody seems to look for Mono.Cecil 0.9.6.0, but I can only find 0.9.5.0 in the packages folder...

I tried downgrading Costura.Fody to 1.3.3.0 and Fody to 1.26.1 but i'm still having the exact same problem.

You can see that other people are having this issue too here:
https://github.com/Fody/Costura/issues/118

Comment: Did you find any compareable alternative to Costura.Fody?

Comment: @ThomasHahn unfortunately no, but Costura is now fixed in version 1.3.5 released this morning.

Answer (score 0):

Costura.Fody 1.4.1 solved the problem

`Install-Package Costura.Fody -Version 1.4.1`

credit goes here [@distantcam](https://github.com/Fody/Costura/issues/184)

Answer (score 0):

it gets fixed when I update Fody package (https://github.com/Fody/Fody) to 3.1.4 version

Answer (score 0):

I went to the nuget folder eg C:/../.nuget\packages\cauldron.interception.fody\3.2.3\netclassicweaver\Cauldron.Interception.Fody.dll

Deleted this cauldron.interception.fody folder.

Then now it started taking value from cauldron.basicinterceptors. andf then build became successful.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by deleting, the obj Folder of the Project.